# How to change the tab size in suckless simple-terminal?

Tags: suckless-terminal

I am trying to figure out how to change the tab size of my st build to 4 spaces in width (still using the tab character) and I did the following, but it didn't work:

I changed the `tabspaces` variable from 8 to 4 and the `it#8` value in *st.info* to `it#4`, as the code in the `config.def.h` file says:

```
/*
 * spaces per tab
 *
 * When you are changing this value, don't forget to adapt the »it« value in
 * the st.info and appropriately install the st.info in the environment where
 * you use this st version.
 *
 *  it#$tabspaces,
 *
 * Secondly make sure your kernel is not expanding tabs. When running `stty
 * -a` »tab0« should appear. You can tell the terminal to not expand tabs by
 *  running following command:
 *
 *  stty tabs
 */
unsigned int tabspaces = 4;
```

I then removed the *config.h* file and then did a `make clean install`.

The tab width did not change though. Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming you followed the other parts of the instruction, you did not mention running `stty tabs`.

Comment: I did that though...