# st - change tab size

Tags: suckless-terminal

I was wondering how to change the tab size in st, because I changed the variable in the code and in the st.info, but it also says to recompile the st.info accordingly. How should I do that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was already asked here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621372/how-to-change-the-tab-size-in-suckless-simple-terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the tab size in suckless simple-terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621372/how-to-change-the-tab-size-in-suckless-simple-terminal)

Comment: No one answered that question (and it's mine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration should be done with `config.h`, not in `st.info`.

There, you can set `unsigned int tabspaces = 8` or what number you prefer.

Comment: I know, I changed it there, but that did not affect my st tabsize.

Comment: That should be it. Where do you want to have the tabs? Could it be a terminal based editor which perhaps overwrites the st settings?

Comment: I want to have it just in my shell. My NeoVim is configured correctly.

Comment: Yeah, no. My shell in st still uses 8 spaces for a tab.

Comment: So I guess you checked  with `echo "|\t|"` what your shell does?

Comment: Yep, it uses 8 spaces.